# How to copy contents from a directory and not symbolic link?

Tags: linux

on a directory `cp -rvf dir .` copies the symbolic links and not actual contents.
src is copied to `module/hal/`

```
.
|-- comm
|   `-- alchemist.c
|-- module
|   `-- hal
|       `-- src
|           `-- comm -> ../comm
`-- src
    `-- comm -> ../comm
```

Comment: midnight commander `mc` check follow links when copying

Answer (score 103, accepted):

From `cp(1)`:

```
   -L, --dereference
          always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```

Comment: Does this switch make `cp` copy the symbolic links as they were real files or directories?

Comment: @SomethingSomething yes, `cp -L source-file destination-file` will treat `source-file` as the file it links to. See this answer for examples: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/94766